# EASY Permutation question

Tags: combinations

Assuming that everyone in a particular school has three initials, find out whatis the smallest number of students in a school for which there must be at leasttwo with the same initials.

Comment: Perhaps if you're having trouble with the question, don't start the title by declaring it to be 'easy' in all-caps....

Comment: @Richard: How many triples of initials can you have?

Comment: What you have you tried?

Comment: I called it easy since I already had an answer in mind, but although David nailed it, I don't understand why the +1.

Comment: @Richard I didn't see your comment yesterday. Consider the simplified problem of only two names per person and there being only 2 letters per initial, say A and B. Then every person would have initials either AA, AB, BA, or BB. So four possibilities. If there were 4+1=5 people in the room, two people must have the same initials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the number of possible unique initial combinations, and add 1. The number of possible initials, assuming capital letters and the english alphabet:

$$26\cdot 26\cdot 26=17576$$

If there were at least $17577$ students, by a concept known as the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), (in this case, common sense really) two people must share initials.